# Can I catch errors and continue to next Rake task?

Tags: ruby, rake

I invoke Rake tasks in another Rake task like following:

```
namespace :test do
  task :migrate do
    Rake::Task['A:migrate'].invoke
    Rake::Task['B:migrate'].invoke
  end
end
```

What I want to know is whether I can continue to the next Rake task even if the earlier one fails. For instance, there is an error in `A:migrate`, I want to catch it and log it but move ahead with `B:migrate`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rake is just Ruby, so you can use Ruby's error handling feature.

```rb
namespace :test do
  task :migrate do
    begin
      Rake::Task['A:migrate'].invoke
    rescue => e
      log(e)
    end
    Rake::Task['B:migrate'].invoke
  end
end
```